# Helm entries run off right edge

Tags: helm

Using my prelude-based emacs install full-screen on my laptop, I normally have 2 vertical windows side-by-side. If I invoke helm-mini, it normally takes up half of one vertical window, so about a quarter of my laptop screen. However when it's showing the full path of recent files, these trail off the right edge of the helm window, hiding the useful file name:

[image]

I know I can hit `C-t` a few times to move the helm window around, and hopefully get a winder window that can hopefully show the file name, but that's cumbersome.

Is there a setting or feature that will help here? Maybe truncating the left side of the line, not the right? Or wrapping the line around? Or something else?

Comment: You can use `C-]` to shorten the paths in `recentf` source, so Helm entries  don't expand the whole screen. Also, disable `linum-mode` in Helm might help.

Comment: `C-]` is a decent hack. Main drawback is that it only works for the current section of helm-mini; so if the cursor is in Buffers, it doesn't shorten recentf. Would still like something automatic.

Comment: You can set `(setq helm-truncate-lines nil)` to avoid truncating the lines. Alternatively, you can use `helm-buffers-list` and `(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)` to enable visited files to be displayed in `helm-buffers-list`. Choose one depends one whether you want to see the full paths or not.

Comment: `helm-truncate-lines` is already nil for me. maybe something else is going on?

Comment: That's right. It has no effect. I used this code instead: `(add-hook 'helm-after-initialize-hook (lambda () (with-helm-buffer (visual-line-mode))))`.

Comment: that works! why didn't you say that in the first place :) add it as an answer and claim your bounty!

Comment: I don't actually use it since I have a pretty big screen. I thought that setting `helm-truncate-line` should solve your problem, since it's the easiest but apparently it's not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To wrap the entries in Helm buffer instead of truncating them, add function to `helm-after-initialize-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'helm-after-initialize-hook (lambda ()
                                        (with-helm-buffer
                                          (visual-line-mode))))
```

Alternatively, you can use `helm-buffers-list` and add this setting: `(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)` to enable visited files to be displayed in `helm-buffers-list`. Choose one depends one whether you want to see the full paths or not.

Answer (score 2):

Take a note that for now. You can use:

- `C-c >` ([helm-toggle-truncate-line](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/a1791980f9ddca1989c65a67e6997bdde481dc27/helm.el#L236)) to truncate lines
- and `C-]` ([helm-ff-run-toggle-basename](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/f0f174138f6f3198a6b970fd29e7caa94236e3bc/helm-types.el#L43)) to toggle the list to the basename only